# Inside an iframe, Jsps are not loading

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp, iframe

I am doing an Eclipse dynamic web project in which I have to use iframe.
The structure as below ...
[In JSP iframe src, Page (html / Jsp) are not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1052m.jpg)

As you can see in the picture, jsps/html is present..to access in home.jsp, I am using the below lines:

```
<iframe name="menuframe" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>\jsp\NewFile.html" style="height: 938px; width: 196px; margin-left: 20px "></iframe>
<iframe name="detailframe" src="../detailframe.jsp" style="width: 655px; height: 938px; margin-left: 20px "></iframe>
```

What makes me strange is, nothing is working when I have tried with all possible combinations.

Kindly suggest me along with the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e3Tim.jpg)

FYI, I have tried with `${pageContext.request}` too but finally no use.

Comment: Can any one help me please with some real helpful answer ...

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are viewing this on an incompatible web browser. Do check the supported browser and hacks for incompatible browsers.

Also there is a concept of cross domains access in iFrame.